# Can't locate element on Pop-Up Window using Selenium on Python

Tags: python, selenium, popup, blocking

I want to scrape some elements from the Duden webpage with this url: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/aussuchen.
When I look up the page manually no pop-up occures but when I use selenium on python this occures: [image of pop up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZz8D.png)

I already tried a lot of things like blocking pop ups in general, or trying to click on the accept button. All of that is not working.

I tried to find an element of the frame and print a statement then to see whether it can find the elements but that is also not working.

Has anyone an idea why it is like that or what I could try more?

These are a few things I tried:

- For blocking:

  ```
  def getAllWordForms(word):

     options = Options()
     profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
     profile.set_preference("dom.disable_open_during_load", False)
     driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile,options=options, executable_path=os.path.join(driver_location, 'geckodriver'))

     main_url = 'https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/'

     word_url = main_url + '{}'.format(word)

     driver.get(word_url)
  ```
- to see if it can find an element in the pop up frame:

  ```
  def getAllWordForms(word):

     options = Options()
     driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path=os.path.join(driver_location, 'geckodriver'))

     main_url = 'https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/'
     word_url = main_url + '{}'.format(word)
     driver.get(word_url)
     driver.implicitly_wait(10)
     driver.switch_to.frame(1)

     if driver.find_elements_by_class_name('message-button'):
        print('yes')
  ```
- to click the button:

  ```
    def getAllWordForms(word):

       options = Options()
       options.headless = False
       driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path=os.path.join(driver_location, 'geckodriver'))

       main_url = 'https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/'
       word_url = main_url + '{}'.format(word)
       driver.get(word_url)
       driver.implicitly_wait(10)
       driver.switch_to.frame(1)
       button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@aria-label='AKZEPTIEREN']")
       button.click()
       driver.switch_to.default_content()
  ```

I tried out various combinations, but it never works.

The elements of the page are structred like this:
[structure of page_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwVzM.png)
[structure of page_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9M3o.png)

Hope I could explain it correct and that maybe someone could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you launch your webdriver you're using a new temporary profile. That profile has no cookies therefore it's seen by the site as a new user an needs to accept the cookie message.

I had a look at your site and to close the message you need to switch iframe. You were close with your solution, it might just be it needed a different method of selecting the frame...

This code works for me:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/aussuchen")

iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[contains(@id,'sp_message_iframe')]")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
cookieAccpet = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='AKZEPTIEREN']")))
cookieAccpet.click()

driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Remember to switch back to the default frame at the end with `driver.switch_to.default_content()`, then you can continue your script.